# Jedis HMSET map insertion order

Tags: java, redis, linkedhashmap, jedis

Jedis has a hmset method which allows you to set a map of fields and their values at a specific key.

I use the method this way:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

                // General player data
                map.put("name", player.getName());
                map.put("ip", player.getAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
                map.put("rank", "none");
                map.put("tokens", "0");
                map.put("coins", "0");

                // Arsenal player statistics
                map.put("ar_score", "0");
                map.put("ar_gameswon", "0");
                map.put("ar_gameslost", "0");
                map.put("ar_kills", "0");
                map.put("ar_deaths", "0");

                pipeline.hmset("uuid:" + uuid, map);

                pipeline.sync();
                core.redis.getJedisPool().returnResourceObject(jedis);
```

I decided to use a LinkedHashMap to retain the insertion order — however, when looking at the database, it still messes up the order.

Does anyone know how to insert it into the database without messing up the order?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The String-based Jedis client [transcodes the strings](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Client.java#L159) using a temporary HashMap, so it kills your order. The BinaryClient [iterates over the Map](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/BinaryClient.java#L241) directly and retains the order.

The [lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) client keeps the order of your map in any case.

Alternatively, set the values one by one using `HSET hash key value`

HTH, Mark

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to Redis based framework for Java - [Redisson](https://redisson.org). It keeps map entries in insertion order during iteration using any codec (`Jackson JSON`, `Avro`, `Smile`, `CBOR`, `MsgPack`, `Kryo`, `FST`, `LZ4`, `Snappy` and `JDK Serialization`).